# How to create entity reference field from custom entity to specific content type

Tags: 8, entities

I'm on Drupal 8, using `BaseFieldDefinition::create('entity_reference')` on my custom entity type to add entity reference field;

I also use this `->setSetting('target_type', 'node')` to get nodes but this gives me all nodes of any content type;

Is there any way or possibility to filter these nodes to specific content type?

Here is the code for my field:

```
$fields['project_id'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('entity_reference')
      ->setLabel(t('Project'))
      ->setDescription(t('The project ID, transaction was created for.'))
      ->setSetting('target_type', 'node')
      ->setSetting('handler', 'default')
      ->setTargetEntityTypeId('project')
      ->setDisplayOptions('view', array(
        'label'  => 'hidden',
        'type'   => 'project',
        'weight' => 0,
      ))
      ->setDisplayOptions('form', array(
        'type'     => 'entity_reference_autocomplete',
        'weight'   => 5,
        'settings' => array(
          'match_operator'    => 'CONTAINS',
          'size'              => '60',
          'autocomplete_type' => 'tags',
          'placeholder'       => '',
        ),
      ))
      ->setDisplayConfigurable('form', TRUE)
      ->setDisplayConfigurable('view', TRUE);
```

I want this field to be referenced to Content Type called `project` and not all types of nodes.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're looking for the handler_settings setting, which provides configuration for the handler you've chosen, in your case, you want:

```
$handler_settings = [
  'target_bundles' => [
    'project' => 'project',
  ],
];
```

As always with fields, widgets and formatters, just create a configurable field in the UI, export it and look at the settings there. You can always copy the settings and other things almost 1:1 from the exported YAML files to a PHP array.

Answer (score 11):

Also you can set it with           `->setSetting('handler_settings',['target_bundles'=>['YOUR_CONTENT_TYPE_MACHINE_NAME'=>'YOUR_CONTENT_TYPE_MACHINE_NAME']] )` , you can pass multi value to it. I mean

```
->setSetting('handler_settings',['target_bundles'=>['YOUR_CONTENT_TYPE_MACHINE_NAME1'=>'YOUR_CONTENT_TYPE_MACHINE_NAME1','YOUR_CONTENT_TYPE_MACHINE_NAME2'=>'YOUR_CONTENT_TYPE_MACHINE_NAME2','YOUR_CONTENT_TYPE_MACHINE_NAME3'=>'YOUR_CONTENT_TYPE_MACHINE_NAME3']] )
```

So the final solution for your case is :

```
$fields['project_id'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('entity_reference')
      ->setLabel(t('Project'))
      ->setDescription(t('The project ID, transaction was created for.'))
      ->setSetting('target_type', 'node')
      ->setSetting('handler', 'default')
      ->setSetting('handler_settings',['target_bundles'=>['project'=>'project']] )
      ->setDisplayOptions('view', array(
        'label'  => 'hidden',
        'type'   => 'project',
        'weight' => 0,
      ))
      ->setDisplayOptions('form', array(
        'type'     => 'entity_reference_autocomplete',
        'weight'   => 5,
        'settings' => array(
          'match_operator'    => 'CONTAINS',
          'size'              => '60',
          'autocomplete_type' => 'tags',
          'placeholder'       => '',
        ),
      ))
      ->setDisplayConfigurable('form', TRUE)
      ->setDisplayConfigurable('view', TRUE);
```

Comment: This was helpful for me to set up an entity_reference field. Do you know if it is possible to:

- use a rendered entity for the display type or view
- use a media/image widget for the form display:

Comment: i.e. I currently I have the following: 

    ->setSetting('handler', 'default')

    ->setDisplayOptions('form', array(
      'type' => 'entity_reference_autocomplete',
      'weight'   => 5,
      'settings' => array(
        'match_operator' => 'CONTAINS',
        'size' => 60,
        'placeholder' => '',
        'autocomplete_type' => 'tags',
        'display_label' => TRUE,
      ),
    ))
    ->setDisplayOptions('view', array(
      'label' => 'hidden',
      'type' => 'list_default',
      'weight' => 0,
    ))